# Mark matches within 7 days of each other - not in 7 day period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a table:

```
----------------------------------------
REF   |  Date      |  Product |  Mark  |
----------------------------------------
1     | 01/01/2014 | A        |   X
1     | 07/01/2014 | B        |   X
1     | 14/01/2014 | C        |   X
1     | 21/01/2014 | A        |   X
1     | 31/01/2014 | A        |   
1     | 06/01/2014 | A        |   X
2     | 01/01/2014 | B        |   
2     | 07/01/2014 | B        |   
2     | 14/01/2014 | F        |   
2     | 21/01/2014 | A        |   
2     | 31/01/2014 | A        |   
2     | 06/01/2014 | D        |
```

I need to put an X in the mark column where for a given ref, e.g. 1, and a given set of Products, e.g. A, B, C the dates are 7 days apart.

e.g. for ref 1

ex1: 01/01/2014 | A  is within 7 days of ex2
ex2: 07/01/2014 | B  is within 7 days of ex1 and ex3
ex3: 14/01/2014 | C  is within 7 days of ex2 and ex4
ex4: 21/01/2014 | A  is within 7 days of ex3

So you can see they are not all within 7 days of each other but are in a string within 7 days of each other.

The other complicating factor is that unless the string includes A, B and C then nothing should be marked!

I think you can see why I'm struggling with this one, any advice is very gratefully received!

Thanks

Dominic

Comment: Why has the row `(1, 06/01/2014, A)` not been marked? Is this not within 7 days of `(1, 01/01/2014, A)`?

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(REF INT,[DATE] DATE,PRODUCT VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1     , '01/01/2014' , 'A' 
UNION ALL       
SELECT 1     , '01/07/2014' , 'B'   
UNION ALL      
SELECT 1     , '01/14/2014' , 'C'   
UNION ALL      
SELECT 1     , '01/21/2014' , 'A'  
UNION ALL       
SELECT 1     , '01/31/2014' , 'A' 
UNION ALL        
SELECT 1     , '01/06/2014' , 'A'  
UNION ALL         
SELECT 2     , '01/01/2014' , 'B'  
UNION ALL       
SELECT 2     , '01/07/2014' , 'B' 
UNION ALL        
SELECT 2     , '01/14/2014' , 'F'
UNION ALL           
SELECT 2     , '01/21/2014' , 'A' 
UNION ALL           
SELECT 2     , '01/31/2014' , 'A'  
UNION ALL          
SELECT 2     , '01/06/2014' , 'D'
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(0)))RNO, *
    FROM #TEMP  
)
SELECT C1.REF,C1.[DATE],C1.PRODUCT,
CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(DAY,C2.[DATE],C1.[DATE]) BETWEEN -7 AND 7
    AND  C1.PRODUCT IN('A','B','C')
    OR DATEDIFF(DAY,C2.[DATE],C1.[DATE]) IS NULL THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END MARK
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO+1 AND C1.REF=C2.REF
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e5ae/3)**

Comment: GarethD you are right this is my first post. In fact ref 2 should have none marked as it doesn't have A,B and C in the "string" of dates. Thanks Savarth, your answer looks close but isn't quite there but it gives me something to think on. I've corrected the example table. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is ur question means we have to select the first date of each RefId and put **X** for the next few date if their date difference is less than or equal to 7? @DominicA

Answer (score 0):

This is marking the records you want...

```
DECLARE @prods TABLE (prod VARCHAR(10), prevprod VARCHAR(10), nextprod VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO @prods (prod , prevprod , nextprod ) 
      SELECT 'A','C','B' 
UNION SELECT 'B','A','C' 
UNION SELECT 'C','B','A'

DECLARE @dates TABLE (REF INT,[DATE] DATE,PRODUCT VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @dates
          SELECT 1, '01/01/2014' , 'A' 
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/07/2014' , 'B'   
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/14/2014' , 'C'   
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/21/2014' , 'A'  
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/31/2014' , 'A' 
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/06/2014' , 'A'  
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/01/2014' , 'B'  
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/07/2014' , 'B' 
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/14/2014' , 'F'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/21/2014' , 'A' 
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/31/2014' , 'A'  
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/06/2014' , 'D'  

SELECT x1.* , 'X' = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM @dates AS x2 
  INNER JOIN @prods AS p2 ON p2.prod = x2.PRODUCT
  WHERE x1.REF = x2.REF AND 
  (
   ( DATEDIFF(day, x1.DATE , x2.DATE) BETWEEN  0 AND 7  AND p1.prod = p2.prevprod )
   OR
   ( DATEDIFF(day, x1.DATE , x2.DATE) BETWEEN -7 AND 0  AND p1.prod = p2.nextprod )
  )
) THEN 'X' ELSE '' END
FROM @dates AS x1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @prods AS p1 ON p1.prod = x1.PRODUCT
```

The results for the original example:

```
REF         DATE       PRODUCT    X
----------- ---------- ---------- ----
1           2014-01-01 A          X
1           2014-01-07 B          X
1           2014-01-14 C          X
1           2014-01-21 A          X
1           2014-01-31 A          
1           2014-01-06 A          X
2           2014-01-01 B          
2           2014-01-07 B          
2           2014-01-14 F          
2           2014-01-21 A          
2           2014-01-31 A          
2           2014-01-06 D
```

Now, as DominicA suggested, if you change

UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/14/2014' , 'C'

to

UNION ALL SELECT 3, '01/14/2014' , 'C'
you will get this results

```
REF         DATE       PRODUCT    X
----------- ---------- ---------- ----
1           2014-01-01 A          X
1           2014-01-07 B          X
3           2014-01-14 C          
1           2014-01-21 A          
1           2014-01-31 A          
1           2014-01-06 A          X
2           2014-01-01 B          
2           2014-01-07 B          
2           2014-01-14 F          
2           2014-01-21 A          
2           2014-01-31 A          
2           2014-01-06 D
```

Comment: Thanks leoinfo, that looks like good code but when I change (UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/14/2014' , 'C' ) to (UNION ALL SELECT 3, '01/14/2014' , 'C' ) it is still marking Ref 1 rows but isn't meeting the criteria of A, B and C all being in the "string" of dates?

Comment: @DominicA - I don't understand... if you change  (UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/14/2014' , 'C' ) to (UNION ALL SELECT 3, '01/14/2014' , 'C' ) what do you think it should be marked? Don't you want to the markings to be made within groups with the same Ref number? Maybe I got it wrong...

Comment: Hi yes but it needs to only mark them when they are A, B or C. So when you make the change I mention it shouldn't mark F AND it shouldn't mark the next A as it is not within 7 days or the previous B.  Bit confusing I know.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Thanks leoinfo for all your efforts, the result of the change of Ref to 3 should result in nothing being marked at all for Ref1 as it doesn't have A, B and C within 7 days of each other.

Comment: Check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understood what you want...

For the original list:

```
    DECLARE @prods TABLE (prod VARCHAR(10), prevprod VARCHAR(10), nextprod VARCHAR(10) )
    INSERT INTO @prods (prod , prevprod , nextprod ) 
          SELECT 'A','C','B' 
    UNION SELECT 'B','A','C' 
    UNION SELECT 'C','B','A'

    DECLARE @dates TABLE (REF INT,[DATE] DATE,PRODUCT VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO @dates
              SELECT 1, '01/01/2014' , 'A' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/07/2014' , 'B'   
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/14/2014' , 'C'   
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/21/2014' , 'A'  
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/31/2014' , 'A' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/06/2014' , 'A'  
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/01/2014' , 'B'  
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/07/2014' , 'B' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/14/2014' , 'F'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/21/2014' , 'A' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/31/2014' , 'A'  
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01/06/2014' , 'D'  

;WITH list AS (
  SELECT 
      REF1 = x1.REF, DATE1 = x1.DATE, PRODUCT1 = x1.PRODUCT
    , REF2 = x2.REF, DATE2 = x2.DATE, PRODUCT2 = x2.PRODUCT
    , REF3 = x3.REF, DATE3 = x3.DATE, PRODUCT3 = x3.PRODUCT
  FROM @dates AS x1 
  INNER JOIN @prods AS p1 ON p1.prod = x1.PRODUCT
  INNER JOIN @dates AS x2 ON x1.REF = x2.REF AND x2.PRODUCT = p1.nextprod AND DATEDIFF(day, x1.DATE , x2.DATE) BETWEEN  1 AND 7
  INNER JOIN @prods AS p2 ON p2.prod = x2.PRODUCT
  INNER JOIN @dates AS x3 ON x2.REF = x3.REF AND x3.PRODUCT = p2.nextprod AND DATEDIFF(day, x2.DATE , x3.DATE) BETWEEN  1 AND 7
)
, list2 as (
  SELECT z.* , 'X' = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
      SELECT * 
      FROM list AS x
      WHERE 
        ( z.REF = x.REF1 AND z.DATE = x.DATE1 AND z.PRODUCT = x.PRODUCT1 )
        OR
        ( z.REF = x.REF2 AND z.DATE = x.DATE2 AND z.PRODUCT = x.PRODUCT2 )
        OR
        ( z.REF = x.REF3 AND z.DATE = x.DATE3 AND z.PRODUCT = x.PRODUCT3 )
    ) THEN 'X' ELSE '' END
  FROM @dates AS z
)

SELECT x.REF, X.DATE, X.PRODUCT, X = CASE WHEN x.X = '' AND EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM @prods AS p 
  INNER JOIN list2 AS x4 ON   x4.X = 'X'
                          AND x4.REF = x.REF 
                          AND x4.PRODUCT = p.prevprod
                          AND DATEDIFF(day, x4.DATE , x.DATE) BETWEEN  1 AND 7
  WHERE p.prod = x.PRODUCT
) THEN 'X' ELSE x.X END
FROM list2 AS x
INNER JOIN @prods AS p ON p.prod = x.PRODUCT
```

The results are:

```
REF         DATE       PRODUCT    X
----------- ---------- ---------- ----
1           2014-01-01 A          X
1           2014-01-07 B          X
1           2014-01-14 C          X
1           2014-01-21 A          X
1           2014-01-31 A          
1           2014-01-06 A          X
2           2014-01-01 B          
2           2014-01-07 B          
2           2014-01-21 A          
2           2014-01-31 A
```

Now, as DominicA suggested, if you change

```
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/14/2014' , 'C'
```

to

```
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '01/14/2014' , 'C'
```

you will get these results:

```
REF         DATE       PRODUCT    X
----------- ---------- ---------- ----
1           2014-01-01 A          
1           2014-01-07 B          
3           2014-01-14 C          
1           2014-01-21 A          
1           2014-01-31 A          
1           2014-01-06 A          
2           2014-01-01 B          
2           2014-01-07 B          
2           2014-01-21 A          
2           2014-01-31 A
```

If you instead change

```
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '01/21/2014' , 'A'
```

to

```
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '01/21/2014' , 'A'
```

you will get these results:

```
REF         DATE       PRODUCT    X
----------- ---------- ---------- ----
1           2014-01-01 A          X
1           2014-01-07 B          X
1           2014-01-14 C          X
3           2014-01-21 A          
1           2014-01-31 A          
1           2014-01-06 A          X
2           2014-01-01 B          
2           2014-01-07 B          
2           2014-01-21 A          
2           2014-01-31 A
```

Comment: The results based on the sample data in the OP do not coincide with the desired output as stated in the OP: record (1, 21/01/2014, 'A') is marked with an 'X' in the OP, whereas in the result set you provide it isn't.